# Testing the titanium mobile web in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, titanium, mobile-website

I am creating the mobile web for an app.The app works fine in running through titanium studio but now i want to test it in iOS simulator and web Without titanium so when i drag the build index.html mobile web browser it just stays on the splash screen.I also have tested the kitchensink and it does the same (working fine in running through titanium studio and not though build index.hmtl).What is possibly that i am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the project in titanium and go into *Resources* folder and then go into *build* folder and then into *iPhone* folder and then run your project in Xcode.

Comment: I am talking of mobile web